# CMake link behaviour depends on BOOST_ROOT

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm using CMake to build a project which among other things link to boost. I use CMake 2.8.7, I have

```
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS true)
```

and I use

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem regex REQUIRED)
```

I then link using

```
target_link_libraries(projectname ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I use the environment variable BOOST_ROOT to specify the location of Boost, and my question is as follows:

When I set

```
BOOST_ROOT=/opt/Boost_1_47
```

CMake passes the full path to the libraries to the linker, whereas if I set

```
BOOST_ROOT=/usr
```

it links using

```
-lboost_filesystem-mt
```

etc. CMakeLists.txt is the same in both cases, the only thing I change is the environment varible BOOST_ROOT. Why doesn't CMake pass the full path in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **linker** is able to find the libraries which are in standard paths like `/lib, /lib64, /usr/lib, /usr/lib64 etc`. So in that case CMake does not feel the need to tell the linker where is the library is located. But in case of `/opt/boost_1_47`, as its not a standard path so **linker** doesn't know where is the library located.

Just try setting the `LINK_DIRECTORIES` in CMake to `Path/To/Boost/Libraries` you will notice a different behavior.